# Can I see an example of a payable function in practical use?

Tags: solidity, ether, remix, addresses, payable

I would like to see an example of a function modified as payable in practice.
I would like for it to accept payment and hold the ether.

I would like to read another function in the same contract that can send the held ether to a specific address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really basic example from https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/15/writing-a-contract-that-handles-ether/:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract CommunityChest {
    function withdraw() public {
        msg.sender.transfer(this.balance);
    }

    function deposit(uint256 amount) payable public {
        require(msg.value == amount);
        // nothing else to do!
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return this.balance;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Where the money this.balance come from?

Comment: It's the ether held by the contract. E.g. the ether sent via calls to `deposit`.

Comment: What happens to money 'paid' to deposit() if nothing is done? What's this (here) exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If money is transferred in a call to `deposit`, then... that's it. It's been transferred. The account that sent the transaction now has less ether and the contract has more ether. `this` is a variable that refers to the contract.

Comment: Alright. That answer my question. I didn't understand that a contract holds a single pot of all the money sent to it.

Comment: See also https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/05/writing-a-banking-contract/ for how to keep track of who contributed what.